# Pure CSS3 or Jquery Menu icons effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day Everyone! :)

I want to put an effects to my icons and i saw this link. http://demo.marcofolio.net/social_css3_display/

and i want my icons to behave like on the demo page. When i try to do it things went wrong on my page. Can anyone help me? here is what i have so far..

pls click the link for my fiddle.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/musub/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go if this is how you want yours to look like ....

HTML

```
<ul class="social" id="css3">
            <li class="delicious">
                <a href="http://www.delicious.com/"><strong>Delicious</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li class="digg">
                <a href="http://digg.com/"><strong>Digg</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li class="facebook">
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><strong>Facebook</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li class="flickr">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/"><strong>Flickr</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li class="linkedin">
                <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/"><strong>LinkedIn</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li class="reddit">
                <a href="http://www.reddit.com/"><strong>Reddit</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li class="rss">
                <a href="http://feeds2.feedburner.com/marcofolio"><strong>RSS</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li class="twitter">
                <a href="http://twitter.com/"><strong>Twitter</strong></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

PURE CSS(EDITTED)

```
.social {position: absolute;top: 2%;left: 2%; list-style:none; width:5%;height:80%;}
.social li {position: relative; display:inline; float:left; width: 100%; height: 10%;margin-top: 20%;background-repeat:no-repeat; }
.social li a { display:block; width:48px; height:48px; padding-top:10px; position:relative; text-decoration:none; }
.social li a strong { font-weight:normal; position:absolute; left:20px; top:-1px; color:#fff; padding:3px; z-index:9999;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 -moz-border-radius:3px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); -webkit-border-radius:3px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border-radius:3px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

li.delicious { background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOCdq.png");background-size: 100% 100%; }
li.digg { background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/J64zZ.png");background-size: 100% 100%; }
li.facebook { background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HuiM.png");background-size: 100% 100%; }
li.flickr { background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3UMF.png"); background-size: 100% 100%;}
li.linkedin { background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVWJ1.png");background-size: 100% 100%; }
li.reddit { background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyJRr.png");background-size: 100% 100%; }
li.rss { background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DVfw.png"); background-size: 100% 100%;}
li.twitter { background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkZPp.png"); background-size: 100% 100%;}

/* SOCIAL ICONS - CSS3 */
#css3:hover li { opacity:0.2; }

#css3 li { -webkit-transition-property: opacity; -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
 -moz-transition-property: opacity; -moz-transition-duration: 500ms; }
#css3 li a strong { opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition-property: opacity, top; -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
 -moz-transition-property: opacity, top; -moz-transition-duration: 300ms; }

#css3 li:hover { opacity:1; }
#css3 li:hover a strong { opacity:1; top:-10px; }
```

And FIDDLE DEMO for your reference [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fT9jJ)
Try to work around this keeping it as base and u will get that effect you want

CHECK THE UPDATED FIDDLE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fT9jJ) now it is responsive ..

Comment: its not working well if i change the width into %. i need to use % to make my image responsive.

Comment: @x'tian sec will convert to %

Comment: can you check out my fiddle so you know how i work on. I can't do it on my page. thank you @Vicky.

Comment: @x'tian http://jsfiddle.net/9ruVq/ check this fiddle and tell me what change you want in it

Comment: Hi @vicky. thanks for the help i already solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

here is a new js fiddle.

[JS Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/musub/2/)

you left out classes for the ul "social" and id "css3" so your code wasnt linking with your css.

you also didnt change the "strong" to the class nav_text

also you need to close your image tags and organize your code for better readability.

Comment: Yey! Its working great.. Thank you so much @sergio Wizenfeld :)

Comment: no problem please check the answer to show the problem has been solved. good luck

Comment: Hey how about the popup text when you hover it? do you know how to do it base on my fiddle? thanks :)

Comment: pop up is already there just change the this line and add the values to where ever you want it to be

#css3 li:hover a .nav_text { opacity:1; position: absolute; top: 10px; }

Answer (score 1):

```
    ul li 
    {
          background-color: #FF4747;
          margin: 4px;
    }

    ul:hover li
    {
       opacity: .3;
    }

    ul li:hover 
    {
      opacity: 5;
      transition-duration:0.5s;              //animation timing
      transition-delay:0.2s;
    }
```

Comment: hey. how about the text popping up when i hover the link? do you know how to do it?